# How to export module on unit test in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have developed an component in React Typescript which is working perfectly fine. Also, I have written an Unit Test for same, but we are getting below error for the Unit Test page

> TS2305: Module '"/app/containers/OrderFailure"' has no exported member 
>   'OrderFailure'.

OrderFailure Compontent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
class OrderFailure extends Component<Props, State> {

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    orderDetails: state.orderReducer,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
      push,
};

const withConnect = connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default withConnect(OrderFailure);
```

Unit Test For Compontent:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { spy, assert } from 'sinon';

import { OrderFailure } from '../index';

describe('<OrderSuccess />', () => {

});

it('should call push with parameter on submit click', () => {

});
```

What I am missing, that while creating build I am getting error of no export

Comment: You do not have export, you have default. Change to `import OrderFailure from '../index';`

Comment: thanks Talgat
Resolved the issue by adding export keyword with class directly

Comment: Don't do that it is incorrect. You are importing just class, without redux properties and methods(mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps). Especially you have test for it `it('should call push with parameter on submit click'`

Comment: Try what I suggested.